# php: cannot modify array in function?

Tags: php

so I am trying to modify an array by adding key and value in a function `modArr`; I expect the var dump to show the added items but I get NULL. What step am I missing here?

```
<?php

$arr1 = array();

modArr($arr1);
$arr1['test'] = 'test';
var_dump($arr);

function modArr($arr) {
    $arr['item1'] = "value1";
    $arr['item2'] = "value2";
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are modifying the array as it exists in the function scope, not the global scope. You need to either return your modified array from the function, use the `global` keyword (not recommended) or pass the array to the function by reference and not value.

```
// pass $arr by reference
$arr = array();
function modArr(&$arr) {
  // do stuff
}

// use global keyword
$arr = array();
function modArr($arr) {
  global $arr;
  //...
}

// return array from function
$arr = array();
function modArr($arr) {
  // do stuff to $arr
  return $arr;
}
$arr = modArr($arr);
```

To learn more about variable scope, check the [PHP docs on the subject](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Answer (score 3):

you have to pass `$arr` by reference: `function modArr(&$arr)`

**edit:** noticed an error in your code: you are passing `modArr($arr1);` but trying to output `$arr`

Comment: For PHP 5.4+, & had removed.